# How to validate request model received with schema defined in openapi3(swagger) specification -NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, openapi, express-openapi-validator

Im looking to find a tool/framework which will allow me to validate/check the model of a received request(s) with a schema thats defined in the swagger documentation.

Comment: Are you seeking recommendations for tools/software libraries for validating requests?

Comment: Yes!Thats what im looking for if you have any good suggestions

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple open source packages for NPM that can validate requests and responses based on a swagger file. Here's one example:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-openapi-validator

```
import * as OpenApiValidator from 'express-openapi-validator';

app.use(
  OpenApiValidator.middleware({
    apiSpec: './openapi.yaml',
    validateRequests: true, // (default)
    validateResponses: true, // false by default
  }),
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Stefan!Do you happen to know any tool in which we can specify a swagger definition path and it validates the request against that specific defintion.Example: Something identical to the feature in swagger-tools (swagger-tools.spec.v2.validateModel)